# Как создать ресурс в виде ссылки на другое окно

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

Пытаюсь сделать по MVVM связку главного окна и окна с формой.
В примере DevExpress есть следующий код названный IWindowService:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMDemo.Services.WindowServiceView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo.Services"
         xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
         xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"
         xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
         DataContext="{dxmvvm:ViewModelSource local:WindowServiceViewModel}">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dialogTemplate">
        <dxlc:LayoutControl Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="300">
            <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <dxmvvm:CurrentWindowService/>
            </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Customer Name:">
                <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding CustomerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </dxlc:LayoutItem>
            <Button Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}">Register</Button>
        </dxlc:LayoutControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<!--#region !-->
<dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <dxmvvm:WindowService ViewTemplate="{StaticResource dialogTemplate}">
        <dxmvvm:WindowService.WindowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Window">
                <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight" />
                <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="ToolWindow" />
            </Style>
        </dxmvvm:WindowService.WindowStyle>
    </dxmvvm:WindowService>
</dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
<!--#endregion-->
<dxlc:LayoutControl Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button Command="{Binding ShowRegistrationFormCommand}">Show Registration Form</Button>
</dxlc:LayoutControl>
```

Здесь в ресурсе (в коде главного окна) описана простая форма *dialogTemplate* на одно поле и кнопку. У меня, конечно же, форма не такая простая и описана уже в другом окне. Прошу ответить хотя бы на то, как правильно описать другое окно в виде ресурса? И если у вас был опыт с DevExpress IWindowService, то как прочитать значения из формы в главном окне?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел. Окно нельзя сделать дочерним от другого окна. Я переделал свою форму в User Control. Далее  нужно подключить namespace и указать его в DataTemplate

```
<UserControl
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:App.Views">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FormTemplate">
            <view:SearchForm/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <dxmvvm:WindowService ViewTemplate="{StaticResource FormTemplate}">
        </dxmvvm:WindowService>
    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
</UserControl>
```